# Drawing on canvas in Android

Tags: android

I am a real noob in drawing things using canvas, bitmaps, and so on. But still, I want to change some code. There is a blue canvas, and I want gradually change its color from blue to green. I completely have no idea how to do that. Can somebody give a clue? (`canvas.drawRGB()` method is used to draw the original picture).

Answer (score 1):

i would try this but i don't think that it's an efficient solution

```
int alpha =250;
int green = 250;

for(int i =0;i<5 ;++i){
canvase.drawARGB(alpha,0,green,0);

    alpha -=50;
    green -=50;

    Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    alpha =5;
    int blue =5;
    for(int i =0 ; i< 5; ++i){
    canvas.drawARGB(alpha,0,0,blue);
    alpha +=50;
    blue +=50;
    Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

Comment: it didn't change to dark blue gradually ?